# Variable might not have been initialized when I'm using @RequiredArgsConstructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm learning about Lombok and I have this error: Variable productRespository might not have been initialized. But I have the @RequiredArgsConstructor. And I'm using Intellij idea. So why do I need to create a constructor if I'm using this annotation? Thank you!

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

    @RequiredArgsConstructor

    @Service
    public class ProductService {

        private final ProductRespository productRespository;

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have some other lombok annotation beside @RequiredArgsConstructor. Try to delombok your class and see do you have ProductRespository as parameter in every constructor that is generated.

Comment: Do you have https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok plug-in installed?

Comment: open another project, lombok plugin has been disabled, re-enable it again.

Comment: if you have updated your lombok plugin, you need to restart idea. See settings->plugins and lombok plugin in installed plugins. There would be "restart ide" green button if this is the case.

Answer (score 25):

You need to install lombok plugin for idea if it is not installed yet.

Comment: I have it installed and still see the issue (with @allArgsConstructor)